# Conditional Formatting not obeying rules

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Why does Excel treat empty cells as a value for conditional formatting when the rule used clearly states:
**Format only cells with:** `Cell Value` `greater than or equal to` **0.0625**
 "0.0625" is clearly **NOT** a null/empty value.
How do you prevent this auto-formatting from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have formulas that are returning *empty strings* (e.g. "") and those are showing false positives for your *'Cell Value greater than or equal to 0.0625'* CF rule. Straight text values could also be contributing to false positives.

Switch to *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following for the *Format values where this formula is true:*.

```
=and(isnumber($A1), $A1>0.0625)
```

That assumes a CF rule affecting a block of cells with A1 in the top-left corner.

Comment: That formula did not work. Cells with the Time value of greater than 0.0625 did not highlight with the chosen format.

Comment: If your time values are actually times and not text that looks like time then that formula should work. I've just tested it and 01:29 AM (*0.06182*) is FALSE while 01:30 AM (*0.06251*) is TRUE.